# What's a good book to read on designing back-office/admin/CMS interfaces?

Tags: learning, books

One of my projects involves designing new features and bits of of interfaces to a back-office system my company uses. Unfortunately, I mainly bring to the table experience and familiarity with consumer-facing apps and websites, not work/productivity applications.

Any recommendation for a good book to get me started?

Comment: Your back end operators are your consumers; you can apply many of the same techniques to make a good interface for them. In particular, look for the things they do most, and make sure almost everything can be done from the keyboard. Back office workers love the efficiency of keyboard input.

Comment: Do you have a book that says that? :-)

Comment: Sadly no, just personal experience developing a call centre web application.

Comment: Sorry, but questions requesting recommendations for books / software / apps / papers etc. would fall into the [shopping request](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) category and aren't really suitable to a Q&A website. The reason for this is that there is no one correct answer, and such recommended items would soon be updated and replaced with newer / better versions making the best answers redundant. Therefore you're better off visiting our Chat site for such discussions, they're not really suitable for this main site I'm afraid.